# Changing instance variable bugs animation in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I am having a problem while trying to make a custom "sliding" object from scratch. I have a view `self.taskView` which should either stick to the left or stick to the right. This is working fine until I try to change the `state` of an instance variable called `self.task`.

This is a (webm) animation of it working "correctly": [working.webm](http://stene.io/files/working.webm)

But this only works when I do NOT change the instance variable `self.task.state`

This is a (webm) animation of it NOT working "correctly": [not_working.webm](http://stene.io/files/not_working.webm)

So I know that it is the code that changes the state of the task that is bugging it because if I just comment out all the `[self setState:BOOL]` statements it works as seen in "working.webm".

Any tips or ideas are appreciated. But I am a novice so please keep it simple if it is possible.

```
// Code to move the green UIview right or left
-(IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    self.origin = CGPointMake(self.taskView.frame.origin.x, self.taskView.frame.origin.y);

} else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

    CGPoint touchLocation = [sender locationInView:self];

    CGPoint location = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x, (self.taskView.frame.size.height/2));

    self.taskView.center = location;

} else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    if (self.origin.x == 0) {
        // Stick right
        if (self.taskView.center.x > ((self.frame.size.width/10)*4)) {
            [self setPosition:NO]; // This sets the position of the view
            [self setState:NO]; // This code is bugging the "animation"

        } else { // Else stick to the left
            [self setPosition:YES];
            [self setState:YES];
        }
    } else {
        // Stick left
        if (self.taskView.center.x < ((self.frame.size.width/10)*6)) {
            [self setPosition:YES];
            [self setState:YES];

        } else { // Else stick right
            [self setPosition:NO];
            [self setState:NO];
        }
    }

    /*[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0.01
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^
     {
         [self.taskView setFrame:position];
     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
     }];*/

} else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) {

}
}

// THIS METHOD IS BUGGING THE "ANIMATION"
- (void)setState:(BOOL)state {
    self.task.state = [NSNumber numberWithBool:state];
}
```

Comment: We need more information, this is very vague

Comment: What information do you need? The videos should display how the problem manifests itself, and as I pointed out in the code its only one method that is creating the bug.

Comment: Are you using a OnPanGestureRecognizer? I understand what the bug is, but I've yet to understand how you implemented this as you included only a short version of the code

Comment: I have added more code now. I am using a UIPanGestureRecognizer, but this bug also occurs if I try to use a UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Comment: Great, another thing I need to know: what's self.task ? is it your UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Comment: self.task is an object that is of the class Task. It resides in the built in database in iOS. The task has absolutely nothing to do with the gesture.

Comment: What does instruments say about the cpu?

Comment: [Instruments](http://i.imgur.com/2HtOYFW.png) say that the load is high, I believe? You tell me?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to run a time-consuming method on the main thread, and that's why your animations are choppy.

Your problem as you mentioned resides here:

```
- (void)setState:(BOOL)state {
    self.task.state = [NSNumber numberWithBool:state];
}
```

This is a method that probably does something more than just changing a property (to my understanding from your comments this is a database object)

What you could do, is to update this object on a background thread:

```
- (void)setState:(BOOL)state {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),^{
       self.task.state = [NSNumber numberWithBool:state];
    });     
}
```

Comment: The method changes the state of the object. The pointer `self.task` points to a database object. I will try your solution now.

Comment: Im sorry. This did not change anything. The "animation lag" is still present and I still need to drag the view twice to move it to the other side.